# Node.js (server side) Javascript templating system - like mason or myghty

Tags: open-source, javascript, node.js, templating

Looking for the server-side (e.g. node.js, file-based (not browser based) JavaScript **port** of the perl's [HTML::Mason](http://www.masonbook.com/book/) or the newer [Mason2](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Mason/lib/Mason/Manual/Components.pod)  or the pythonic [Myghty](http://pythonhosted.org//Myghty/embedding.html) template system.

For limiting the wrong recommendations, exactly want a template system what:

- compiles the template sources into pure javascript objects (at first run, and caches the compiled objects for later executions)
- has implemented the `autohandlers` - e.g. `call_next` logic with automatic methods inheritance
- has implemented the `dhandlers` logic
- open source